# Can i use a wildcard in os.path.ismount() in python

Tags: python-2.7

i Would like to check if there are any /decrypt* mount points.Using wildcard with os.path.ismount() was my best guess, but it doesn't work. What can I do then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`glob.glob(pattern)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to expand the wildcard into a list of candidates to pass to `os.path.ismount`.

```
for path in glob.glob(pattern):
    if os.path.ismount(path):
        print(path)  # Or do whatever else you want to do with the mounts.
```

Comment: Thnaks babbageclunk@ its working perfectly for my use case